# JQuery code not showing another linked list onhover by getting ID name

Tags: jquery, conditional-statements, onhover

I have a large mega menu which i have to put in my company website. Now the problem is, many menus are linked with a list of sub menus. I cannot make sub ul/child list of every li bcz of database fetching limitations. So, the idea was, it can be possible through JQuery. I do want to apply condition of every list individually on its sublist to open. So, I was trying to write a smart code but its not working yet. 
"The issue as per sample, third list is not showing on hover"
The help would be much appreciated, Thanks

```js
$(function() {
  $("#ms").hover(
    function() {
      $("#deptms").removeClass('hidden');
      $("#deptss").addClass('hidden');
    }
  );
  $("#ss").hover(
    function() {
      $("#deptss").removeClass('hidden');
      $("#deptms").addClass('hidden');
    }
  );
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('a.subparent').hover(function() {
    list = $(this).attr('id');
    $("#ul_" + list).removeClass('hidden');
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">
  <ul>
    <li class="waves-effect waves">
      <a href="" id="ms"><i class="fa fa-pull-right fa-angle-double-right"></i>Faculty of Management Sciences</a>
    </li>
    <li class="waves-effect waves">
      <a href="" id="ss"><i class="fa fa-pull-right fa-angle-double-right"></i>Faculty of Social Sciences</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 subparent">
  <ul id="deptms" class="hidden">
    <li class="waves-effect waves">
      <a href="" id="ba"><i class="fa fa-pull-right fa-angle-double-right"></i>Department of Business Administration</a>
    </li>
    <li class="waves-effect waves">
      <a href="" id="mc"><i class="fa fa-pull-right fa-angle-double-right"></i>Department of Commerce</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="hidden" id="deptss">
    <li class="waves-effect waves">
      <a href="" id="eco"><i class="fa fa-pull-right fa-angle-double-right"></i>Department of Economics</a>
    </li>
    <li class="waves-effect waves">
      <a href="" id="psy"><i class="fa fa-pull-right fa-angle-double-right"></i>Department of Psychology</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">
  <ul id="ul_ba" class="hidden">
    <li class="waves-effect waves">
      <a href="">Programs</a>
    </li>
    <li class="waves-effect waves">
      <a href="">Key Personnels</a>
    </li>
    <li class="waves-effect waves">
      <a href="">Research</a>
    </li>
    <li class="waves-effect waves">
      <a href="">Student Counselling</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="ul_mc" class="hidden">
    <li class="waves-effect waves">
      <a href="">Programs</a>
    </li>
    <li class="waves-effect waves">
      <a href="">Key Personnels</a>
    </li>
    <li class="waves-effect waves">
      <a href="">Research</a>
    </li>
    <li class="waves-effect waves">
      <a href="">Student Counselling</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: `$("a.subparent")` doesn't match anything. The `subparent` class is on the `<div>`, not the `<a>`.

Answer (score 0):

`a.subparent` is the wrong selector, because the `subparent` class is on the `<div>`, not the `<a>`.

The selector for an `<a>` *inside* the `<div>` is `.subparent a`

```js
$(function() {
  $("#ms").hover(
    function() {
      $("#deptms").removeClass('hidden');
      $("#deptss").addClass('hidden');
    }
  );
  $("#ss").hover(
    function() {
      $("#deptss").removeClass('hidden');
      $("#deptms").addClass('hidden');
    }
  );
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.subparent a').hover(function() {
    list = $(this).attr('id');
    $("#ul_" + list).removeClass('hidden');
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">
  <ul>
    <li class="waves-effect waves">
      <a href="" id="ms"><i class="fa fa-pull-right fa-angle-double-right"></i>Faculty of Management Sciences</a>
    </li>
    <li class="waves-effect waves">
      <a href="" id="ss"><i class="fa fa-pull-right fa-angle-double-right"></i>Faculty of Social Sciences</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4 subparent">
  <ul id="deptms" class="hidden">
    <li class="waves-effect waves">
      <a href="" id="ba"><i class="fa fa-pull-right fa-angle-double-right"></i>Department of Business Administration</a>
    </li>
    <li class="waves-effect waves">
      <a href="" id="mc"><i class="fa fa-pull-right fa-angle-double-right"></i>Department of Commerce</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="hidden" id="deptss">
    <li class="waves-effect waves">
      <a href="" id="eco"><i class="fa fa-pull-right fa-angle-double-right"></i>Department of Economics</a>
    </li>
    <li class="waves-effect waves">
      <a href="" id="psy"><i class="fa fa-pull-right fa-angle-double-right"></i>Department of Psychology</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3">
  <ul id="ul_ba" class="hidden">
    <li class="waves-effect waves">
      <a href="">Programs</a>
    </li>
    <li class="waves-effect waves">
      <a href="">Key Personnels</a>
    </li>
    <li class="waves-effect waves">
      <a href="">Research</a>
    </li>
    <li class="waves-effect waves">
      <a href="">Student Counselling</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="ul_mc" class="hidden">
    <li class="waves-effect waves">
      <a href="">Programs</a>
    </li>
    <li class="waves-effect waves">
      <a href="">Key Personnels</a>
    </li>
    <li class="waves-effect waves">
      <a href="">Research</a>
    </li>
    <li class="waves-effect waves">
      <a href="">Student Counselling</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Man, this help me a lot. I am not expert in jQuery that's why i missed very little point.

Comment: It's not specific to jQuery, it's the same as ordinary CSS selectors.